# Which method does Set.removeAll() use underneath: equals or compareTo?

Tags: java, dictionary, set

Consider the code:

```
class A {

  private int i;

  boolean equals( Object t) {
      if (this == t)
          return true;
      if (!( t instanceof A))
          return false;
      if (this.i == t.i);
  }

}

Map<String,A> orig;
Map<String,B> dup;
```

I am trying to do this

```
orig.entrySet().removeAll(dup.entrySet());
```

I see that the equals method is called; is this always true, or might it call compareTo instead?

Comment: Set is an interface. The removeAll behavior depends on the implementation. I believe that HashSet uses equals while TreeSet uses compare or compareTo.

Comment: just a little note: the last line of your equals is not correct (just a NOP). Probably you wanted something like:  
    "return this.i == ((A)t).i;"

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it calls `equals()`. `compareTo()` could only be used if the `Set` *knew* that it contained `Comparable` objects (sorted sets, for instance, might possibly do this).

Comment: I meant is it only equals or it does it look at compareTo etc and I need to implement those for Class A as well

Comment: I see. I've changed my answer, and you might want to change the question to spell this out more clearly.

Comment: It's Map's entry set. Event for a TreeMap it wouldn't know the contents are Comparable.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the implementation.

For instance, a `HashSet` will use `hashCode` and `equals`. A `TreeSet` will probably use `compareTo`. Ultimately, so long as your types behave appropriately it shouldn't matter.

Comment: This is for the value on the entry set, so TreeMap wont have a suitable Copmarator and the value is not necessarily (and not in this case) Comparable.

Comment: Tom: Looking through the code, it certainly looks to me like if will use compareTo for the key, and then equality for the value.

Answer (score 1):

The TreeSet uses the compareTo, try this:

```
public class A {

    private int i;

    A(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object t) {
        if (this == t)
            return true;
        if (!( t instanceof A))
            return false;
        return (this.i == ((A)t).i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> remove = Arrays.asList(new A(123), new A(789));
        Set<A> set = new TreeSet<A>(new Comparator<A>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(A o1, A o2) {
                return o1.i - o2.i;  
                // return 0; // everything get removed
            }
        });
        set.add(new A(123));
        set.add(new A(456));
        set.add(new A(789));
        set.add(new A(999));

        set.removeAll(remove);
        for (A a : set) {
            System.out.println(a.i);
        }
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

make the Comparator always return 0 and everything will be removed! Same happens if not using a Comparator but implementing Comparable.

The TreeSet is based on a TreeMap which uses the compareTo in getEntry.
In the Javadoc of the TreeSet you can (finally) read:

> ...the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a **TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo** (or compare) method...

[]]

Answer (score 1):

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

"Implementations are free to implement optimizations whereby the equals invocation is avoided, for example, by first comparing the hash codes of the two elements."

Most likely will use equals, but considering the statement above, you cannot fully rely on equals() to be called. Remember that it's always a good idea to override hashCode() whenever you override equals().

Answer (score 0):

Some `Set` implementations rely on `hashCode` (e.g. `HashSet`). That is why you should always override `hashCode` too when you override `equals`.

Comment: You should indeed override hashCode, but HashSet also calls equals() just to be safe.

Comment: mmeyers: If two equals objects don't exactly the same hashCode (because they don't override it for example) then they may never have equals called on them. Likewise, even if they do have the same hashCode, there is no reason why objects should be equal.

Comment: Yes; I wasn't sure whether the question was "do I need to override equals?" or "is equals the only method I need to override?"

Answer (score 0):

The only implementation within the Java library that I am aware of that wont do this is [IdentityHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html). [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) for instance does not have an appropriate `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where compareTo is used; the javadoc for remove() for the Map interface says "More formally, if this map contains a mapping from key k to value v such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)), that mapping is removed." While for the Set interface it similarly says "More formally, removes an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)), if the set contains such an element."

Note that removeAll()'s javadoc doesn't say how it operates, which means, as others have said, that it's an implementation detail.

In Sun's Java, according to Bloch in his Effective Java (if I remember correctly), it iterates over the collection and calls remove(), but he stresses that you must never assume that's how it's always done.